# "In the hope of" vs. "with the hope of"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

While solving a question I encountered a situation when there was a subtle difference between the two:

> After meeting together near Mediolanurn in 313, Roman Emperors
>   Constantine Augustus and Licinius Augustus issued *The Edict of Milan*
>   **in the hope of/with the hope of** ending years of internal religious strife and the persecution of minorities.

I think *with* sounds more appropriate. But I am not sure about the usage of *in*.

Could anyone explain the correct usage in this sentence? Also give some instances where we can use the latter one.

Comment: *Mediolanurn* appears to be a [common typo](https://www.google.com/#q=Mediolanurn&nfpr=1&ei=_wvzUKKHK-rrigLPmYHAAQ&sqi=2&start=0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1357700187,d.cGE&fp=5a56163368071ca0&biw=1053&bih=579) (21000 hits) for *[Mediolanum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediolanum)* (3.3 million hits)

Comment: If you found this material elsewhere, and it's under copyright, please cite your source.

Answer (score 11):

A quick comparison in [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) shows that **in the hope** is more commonly used.

Even [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hope) has this expression used in its example sentence to demonstrate the usage of *hope*.

> **hope**
>
> feeling of expectation and desire for a particular thing to happen:
>
> he looked through her belongings **in the hope of** coming across some information

Though **in the hope of** and **with the hope of** are pretty much interchangeable.

Please take note that **in hopes of** can have a different meaning, as suggested by the New Oxford American Dictionary. (I don't find it in other dictionaries though.)

> **in hopes of**
>
> with the aim of: I lay on a towel in the park in hopes of getting a tan.

Comment: Please give the reference.

Comment: @Sudhir Sure. And I'm sorry for failing to notice that your question is about *in the hope of* instead of *in hopes of* just now.

Comment: Is there any difference between in hopes of and in hope of ?

Comment: @Sudhir Yes. When we use *in hopes of* , we have the tendency to mean *with the aim of*. Though sometimes it can just mean *in the hope of*, it depends on the context.

Comment: I'd say that 'he looked through her belongings in the hope of coming across some information' also shows an aim.

Answer (score 2):

Both are grammatical. There seems to be little difference in meaning, but a detailed corpus search might show that they were used in different contexts. What corpus evidence does show is that *in the hope* is more popular than *with the hope*. It occurs nearly four times as much in the Corpus of Contemporary American English, and nearly eighteen times as much in the British National Corpus.

Answer (score 1):

All variants of *hope* in this context are somewhat informal, and therefore don't really match the tone of OP's sentence. So I'd suggest using *"with the aim/intention of"*.

In less formal contexts, I would slightly favour *"**in** the hope of"*. But it really is just a stylistic choice between several alternatives, *all of which would normally be semantically identical...*

[image] [Source](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&corpus=26&year_end=2019&content=in%20the%20hope%20of%2Cwith%20the%20hope%20of%2Cin%20the%20hopes%20of%2Cwith%20the%20hopes%20of%2Cin%20hope%20of%2Cin%20hopes%20of%2Cwith%20hope%20of%2Cwith%20hopes%20of&year_start=1919&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20hope%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20the%20hope%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20hopes%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20the%20hopes%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20hope%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20hopes%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20hope%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20hopes%20of%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20hope%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20the%20hope%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20hopes%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20the%20hopes%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20hope%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20hopes%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20hope%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20hopes%20of%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Is there any difference between *in hopes of* and *in hope of* ?

Comment: @Sudhir: So far as I'm concerned, the only difference is that with 19,800,000 hits in Google Books, [in hopes of](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22in+hopes+of%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is about three times more common than the singular version. I'd say they always *mean* exactly the same thing.

Comment: What is your source for “in hopes of” being more common? [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&year_end=2019&smoothing=3&content=in+the+hope+of%2Cin+hopes+of&corpus=26&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20hope%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20hopes%20of%3B%2Cc0) shows the opposite (and same with “in the hope that” vs “in hopes that”) since the early 1800s, with “in hopes of” gaining popularity in the US recently.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil': Sudhir asked about the difference between ***in hopes of*** and ***in hope of*** (singular or plural). You compared the more common version of those two (plural ***in hopes of***) with the ***article + singular*** version ***in the hope of***. Note that there's also the ***article + plural*** permutation ***in the hopes of***, but that's the least common of the lot.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ah, it took me a while to understand your reply: the hazards of communication… I was following up on your answer, not on the comment. Your answer states ‘ I think the most common phrasing overall is actually "in hopes of"‘. You don't explicitly state what ‘overall’ covers, but presumably it includes at least the alternatives mentioned in the question: ‘in the hope of’ and ‘with the hope of’. So your answer claims that ‘in hopes of’ is more common than ‘in the hope of’, but that doesn't match my experience or the Ngram result. So I was wondering if it's regional or something.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil': I should admit that *I was following up on your **comment**, not on my **answer**!* I'll edit to repair the situation later when I have time.

Comment: ...note that there are simply too many irrelevant permutations here to cover all of them. *...in hopes **of** winning, ...in hopes **that** [I will win]*, etc. And frankly I don't think it makes a blind bit of difference which of the most common half-dozen or more forms you choose. They're all effectively equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say **in the hope of + doing (gerund)** or **with the hope + that + clause (S-V-O)**
More people are moving to cities in the hope of finding jobs.
More people are moving to cities with the hope that they will find jobs.
Your thoughts?

Comment: Hello, Tran. This asks about a separate question, adding a third (again grammatical) paraphrase.

Answer (score 0):

For the actual answer to the GMAT question, this question is now [online](http://sutariaservices.com/platinumgmat.com/Archive/public_html/about_gmat/sc_practice_question?practice_question_id=94) as a practice GMAT question. The OP seems to have remembered the choices incorrectly. The correct choices are:

> A)    in the hopes to ending
> B)  in the hope to ending
> C)  with the hope to ending
> D)  with the hope of ending
> E)  in the hope to end

The key to answering this question is not *in* versus *with*, but the preposition after *hope*. Note that all but one of the answers have the wording *in/with the hope(s) **to** end(ing).* We don't use *the hope **to** end(ing)*, but *the hope **of** ending*. Both *in* and *with* would be correct in this sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Longman dictionary says:
in the hope of doing something (=because you hope that you will do something)
Shoppers flocked to the sales in the hope of finding a bargain.

Webster dictionary says:
: wanting something to be true : hoping that something will happen
She went back to the restaurant with hopes of finding her purse there

Oxford dictionary says:
in ~ of, in the ~ that I am writing to you in the hope that you can help me obtain some information.

Comment: So how do these definitions apply to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I've just changed 'in hopes of' to 'in the hope of' in a book I'm copy-editing. They mean the same, but 'in hopes of' seems to me to be inappropriately informal/colloquial for an academic book. I'm British and the book is a British publication.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, Glynis. Please look at the research accompanying the upvoted answers.  Also note that OP specifically asks about _in the hope of/with the hope of_. Your comment about 'in hopes of' seeming a less formal variant doesn't address the question proper but may well be a valuable addition to the thread, but it needs better endorsement than 'it seems to me' in an answer suitable for ELU.

Answer (score -2):

In the hope of is quite singular indicating one hope however, in the hopes of is plural and indicates there is more than one hope.

Comment: The question was comparing "In the hope of" against "with the hope of", both of which are singular.