# Is it all right to use "in hopes of" to mean "with the aim of"?

Tags: meaning, idioms, expressions, dictionaries

Recently I browsed through the definition of  *hope* in New Oxford American Dictionary (provided by Apple in the dictionary app) to double confirm with its usage as I [answered](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/97796/11433) a word-choice [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97795/in-the-hope-of-vs-with-the-hope-of) and  came across this:

> **in hopes of**
>
> with the aim of: I lay on a towel in the park in hopes of getting a tan.

I naturally accepted it without a second thought as it is in a pretty authorized dictionary and it looked alright. However, as I answered OP's question, I could see his/her doubt regarding this definition. So I decided to look it up on the Internet and to my astonishment, I couldn't find much evidence supporting that *in hopes of* has the meaning "*with the aim of*". [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/in+hopes+of) and [Merriam-webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hope) even suggest *in hopes of* should just be used normally to mean "hoping something", like *in the hope of*.

> hope
>
> desire accompanied by expectation of or belief in fulfillment: came **in hopes of** seeing you

Therefore my conclusion is: the definition of *in hopes of* depends on the context.

But it is not easy to tell just from a sentence though.  For example,

> John went to MIT in hopes of finding a girlfriend.

It can be interpreted as "*John went to MIT, hoping that he could find a girlfriend*" or "*John went to MIT and his intention was to find a girlfriend*". One has to know what kind of person John was or what he did in MIT to decide what *in hopes of* means in this scenario.

So my question here is:

is it actually "safe" to use the phrase *in hopes of* to mean *with the aim of* ?

Do most people consider *in hopes of* entirely the same as *in the hope of* in terms of meaning? Will they misinterpret it when it is supposed to mean *with the aim of*?

Comment: Yes, there is no grammatical rule which states one cannot use such a phrase in modern English writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would agree with the *with the aim of* definition, but with the addition that it should have enough chance of failure to warrant a degree of hope.

"I went to the corner shop, with the aim of buying some milk" (or simply "to buy some milk") is a straight-forward plan and its execution. You'd expect me to soon have some milk.

"I went to the corner shop, in hopes of buying some milk" would imply that the shop often didn't have milk,* so it was in no way a given that I would succeed.

*Or that I was really absent minded, or didn't know where the shop is, or some other reason that could lead to the plan failing.

Answer (score 0):

Why would anyone pluralize a word that is sufficient to complete a thought in the singular? Also, the pluralization of the word HOPE transforms it to indicate that there is more than one when there is truly only one HOPE that is being conveyed.

My belief is that to pluralize the word hope is truly poor grammar!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).