# Usage of "In the hope that"

Tags: word-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it all right to use “in hopes of” to mean “with the aim of”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97806/is-it-all-right-to-use-in-hopes-of-to-mean-with-the-aim-of)

Which of the following is preferable: "I'm doing this in the hope that it will be helpful to someone", or "I'm doing this in the hope that it is helpful to someone"?

Answer (score 3):

> I'm doing this in the hope that it will be helpful to someone.

I personally prefer the second sentence to the first one.

*Hope* is a feeling of expectation and *will* expresses the emergence of a future event. *I'm doing* something and *I'm* expecting it to be helpful to someone in the future.

> I'm doing this in the hope that it is helpful to someone.

Of course, it is perfectly fine to express it this way too.

The word *is* indicates that what *I'm doing* has a consequence to *someone* in the presence and *I'm* uncertain if it is *helpful* so *I'm in the hope* that it is.